# Displaying random ad in my website using php

Tags: php, file, random, page-refresh

I need to display random Advertisement in my webpage. I am using separate files to display ads

**i.e., 1.txt, 2.txt .. 10.txt**

Each files should be displayed in every refresh of page.
I mean 1.php should be displayed in first refresh and 2.php should be displayed on another refresh. It might be random. but all the pages should be displayed randomly

How can i do this using `rand`  function in php ?

Here is what i tried.

```
$result_random = rand(1,10); 
if($result_random <= 2)
{ 
require ('ad1.txt');
}
```

But i don't know how to proceed. How can i do this ?

Comment: `require ('ad'.rand(1, 10).'.txt')` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [Codepen](http://codepad.viper-7.com/pLAI67) :

Here is the [w3schools working](http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_math_rand)

As simple :

```
<?php 
$result_random = rand(1,10); 
if($result_random <= 2){ 
require ('ad1.txt');
} 
else if($result_random <= 4){ 
require ('ad2.txt');
}
else if($result_random <= 6){ 
require ('ad3.txt');
}
else if($result_random <= 8){ 
require ('ad4.txt');
}
else { 
require ('ad5.txt');
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

For more reference [<kbd>rand()</kbd>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php)

```
$result_random = rand(1,10); 
require ('ad'.$result_random.'.txt');
```

use like this if your `.txt` file name like, ad1.txt,ad2.txt

Comment: This is correct; everyone else's solutions are overthinking it.

Answer (score 1):

Check <kbd>**[demo Codeviper](http://codepad.viper-7.com/tTAlCa)**</kbd> , try this easiest way,

#### PHP

```
<?php
    $input = array("1.php", "2.php", "3.php", "4.php", "5.php");
    $rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);

    echo $input[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";   /* include $input[$rand_keys[0]]; */
    echo $input[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n";   /* include $input[$rand_keys[1]]; */
?>
```

---

**include()**  - behavior occur warning so the rest of the script will still execute.

**require()** -  behavior occur fatal error, which stops execution immediately.

So in this case you should use `include()` function instead of `required()` function,

***Final PHP code,***

```
<?php
    $input = array("1.php", "2.php", "3.php", "4.php", "5.php");
    $rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);

    include $input[$rand_keys[0]]; 

    include $input[$rand_keys[1]];
?>
```

Comment: But 1.php is displaying all the time